# find the: $Cl(M), Int(M), Bd(M)$ in the space $\mathbb{R^2}$ and in a subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R^2},t)$ be the real plane with the usual topology, given the sets

$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: y=0 \; \; \text{and}\; \;   x\in [0,+\infty)\}$

$M=\{ (x,y ) \in \mathbb{R^2}:y=0 \; \; \text{and}\; \;   x\in (1,2)\}$

find the: $Cl(M), Int(M), Bd(M)$ in the space $\mathbb{R^2}$
and $Cl(M), Int(M), Bd(M)$ in the subspace $A$

---

in $\mathbb{R^2}$ : $Cl(M)=[x,0], x\in (1,2)\} $

$Int(M)=(x,0), x\in (1,2)$

$Bd(M) = Cl(M) \setminus Int(M)= \{0,x\}$

In order to find these sets in $A$ i need to take $Cl(M)\cap A$...?

If that's true then the sets will be exaclty the same since $Cl(M)\subseteq A$ and  $Cl(M)\cap A = Cl(M)=[0,x], x\in (1,2)\}$, and same for the other 2 sets.

I don't think this is  correct, can someone verify/give an answer ?

Also, I know my notation is a bit unusual but that's how my notes are, I denote the closure with $Cl()$ the interior with $Int()$ and the boundry with $Bd()$

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $M$ in the plane is $M$ with its two "endpoints" added, that is, $\{(x,0) : x\in[1,2]\}=[1,2]\times\{0\}$. This is also a subset of $A$, so it is equally well the closure of $M$ in $A$.  As a subset of $A$, $M$ is open, so it equals its own interior, and the boundary of $M$ is the two endpoints $\{(1,0),(2,0)\}$. As a subset of the plane, $M$ has no interior points. (There is no point $p\in M$ for which an open neighborhood in the plane is contained in $M$.) That is, its interior is empty, so its boundary equals its closure.